# useState how to set the initial long value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state

There is a very large state that I get from json, that consists of at least 50 lines.

When generating the page, it gives the error "there is no such value" if you do not set the value initially and assign the interface

```
const [dataPosibleValue, setDataPosibleValue]:[IStatPokemon,Dispatch<SetStateAction<IStatPokemon>>] = useState('')
```

Is it possible not to set the value at the beginning so that there is no error during generation?

Comment: "not to set the value" means setting the value to `undefined`, which would result in the same error. I am not an expert in typescript but I think what you have to do is to set the type of `dataPosibleValue` to `IStatPokemon|undefined`.

Comment: By the way, note that you can also type it by `const [dataPosibleValue, setDataPosibleValue] = useState<IStatPokemon>()`. It's a bit more concise and there's no need to type the setter excplicitly then.

Comment: Maybe `useState<IStatPokemon | null>(null);` should do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can only set it, if you have it. If you have it you can set it by passing it into the function like so:

```
const [dataPosibleValue, setDataPosibleValue]:[IStatPokemon,Dispatch<SetStateAction>] 
  = useState('your initial long value')
```

Comment: oh my god, otherwise there is no way?

Comment: You're probably accessing an empty value, so add if condition to check do you have value, or initially set the value.